# Is there a way to shorten this RSpec example to stop code repetition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm on the last chapter of [this excellent Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top) and I've come upon this code:

```
describe "creating a relationship with Ajax" do
  it "should increment the Relationship count" do
    expect do
      xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
    end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "should respond with success" do
    xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

I was wondering if there was any way to stop the repetition, similar to the following code (which won't work as it only creates 2 tests)?

```
it "should increment relationships count" do
  expect do
    xhr :post, :create, relationship: { followed_id: other_user.id }
    response.should be_success        
  end.to change(Relationship, :count).by(1)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a DRY issue. You should separate incrementing test & success response

Comment: Looking at it now, I think I'm just being awkward! Wanted to double check though. Thanks!